# Select 2 most expensive cars for every city

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

I would like to select 2 most expensive cars for every city.

DDL below:

```
create table city_car 
(
    id bigserial,
    city varchar(255),
    car varchar(255),
    price int,
    primary key (id)
);

insert into city_car(city, car, price) 
values
    ('los angeles', 'kia rio', 550),
    ('los angeles', 'audi a4', 1800),
    ('los angeles', 'lexus nx', 2000),
    ('los angeles', 'chevrolet camaro', 2800),
    ('los angeles', 'mazda 6', 1300),
    ('moscow', 'mazda 3', 1000),
    ('moscow', 'kia cerato', 1000),
    ('moscow', 'lexus nx', 2100),
    ('moscow', 'lexus lx', 5000),
    ('moscow', 'bmw x6', 5000),
    ('prague', 'skoda octavia', 1000);
```

Output should be the same as list below with all columns:

```
city          name              price
-----------------------------------------
'los angeles' 'lexus nx'         2000 
'los angeles' 'chevrolet camaro' 2800 
'moscow'      'lexus lx'         5000 
'moscow'      'bmw x6'           5000 
'prague'      'skoda octavia'    1000
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[greatest-n-per-group](/questions/tagged/greatest-n-per-group) problems are typically solved using [window functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-window.html):

```
select city,car,price
from (
  select *, 
         dense_rank() over (partition by city order by price desc) as rnk
  from city_car
) t
where rnk <= 2
order by city, price desc;
```

Depending on how you want to deal with the highest value appearing twice, you can change `dense_rank()` to `row_number()`

Online example: http://rextester.com/ALKZ85776

Comment: Based on the example data it's probably a `ROW_NUMBER` instead of `DENSE_RANK`